# Proving that in a Cayley table, every elements appear once and only once per row and per column

Tags: abstract-algebra, cayley-table

How would one go about to proving that in a Cayley table, every elements appear once and only once in every row and in every column?

Consider group $(G,\cdot)$. Let $x^{-1}$ be the inverse of $x$, and let $e$ be the identity.

$x^{-1} x = e$

$x y = g = x z$

$y = e  y = (x^{-1} x) y = x^{-1} (x  y) = x^{-1}g = x^{-1} (x  z) = (x^{-1} x)  z = e  z = z,$

which seems to be a contradiction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (A good place to start is simply using the definition of a row of a Cayley table....)

Comment: I will add my solution to the problem, but it is incorrect I believe.

Comment: @Johny People love it when you do that on this site! That way they can tell you only what you need to fix, instead of having to spend a ton of their time creating a whole new answer.

Comment: Tip for writing clean proofs: if you mention certain variables but don't actually use them anywhere (in this case, $n$ and $g$), then ask yourself whether you really need them.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't derive a contradiction, you've actually just proved left cancellation: If $xy = xz$ then $y=z$, i.e., you may cancel the $x$'s off the left side.

This means that in a row, each element may only occur at most once, or else it would violate the left cancellation law. Similarly, there is right cancellation, which will imply the same thing for the columns.

What's left is to prove every element occurs at least once in each row/column. Consider the $x$ row, and some arbitrary element $y$. Can you find an element $z$ such that $xz=y$ (and for the column case, $zx=y$)? Hopefully this will be easy to spot!